# Song position difference between mp3 and flac. How to fix this? C#

Tags: audio, position, mp3, difference, flac

I am using Winforms and WindowsMediaPlayer to create a music player. In the form I have a pictureBox with a waveform rendered by NAudio which is saved to an image and loaded upon song change.
when mouseDown the song currentPosition changes to the mouse position over the waveform image.

With mp3 it works very accurate but when I play a flac file the position is very inaccurate.

(the waveform image for mp3 and flac is identical)

Should it have something to do with bitrate?

mp3 = 256 Kbps - Length = 07:44

flac = 892 Kbps - Length = 07:44

f.i.:

flac (x) | mp3 (y)

[ x and y represent mouse position and current song position to be at same real song position (what you hear) ]

1. somewhere in the beginning:

- mousePosition: (x)30 | (y)44
- currentSongPosition: (x)109 | (y)159

2. near the end:

- mousePosition: (x)453 | (y)450
- currentSongPosition: (x)1623 | (y)1607

This is my mouseDownEvent:

```
private void pbWaveForm_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    double timePos = 0;
    pnlWaveScrub.Height = pbWaveForm.Height;

    double MousePosition = e.X;  
    double dur = musicPlayer.currentMedia.duration;
    double ratio = MousePosition / (pbWaveForm.Width );
    timePos = ratio * dur;
            
    musicPlayer.controls.currentPosition = (int)timePos;
    //MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString((int)timePos) + " " + MousePosition.ToString());
}
```

I am planning an if statement with:

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo()
if (f.Extention.Equals(".flac"))
{
    // code to calculate different timePos 

    timePos = differentTimepos
    musicPlayer.controls.currentPosition = (int)timePos;
}
```

If anyone can improve my code I would be delighted with it, thanks!